# React - const changing with state but I don't want it to

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I'm facing this issue in react:

I have an array in a state and I also need to track it's length so that I can know when it's been modified.

```
const [myArray, setMyArray] = useState(["Some Value", "Some other value"]); 

const myArrayLength = myArray.length;
```

At some point in the code:

```
setMyArray([ ...myArray, "add a value"]);

console.log(myArray.length) // Output: 3
console.log(myArrayLength) // Output: Also 3!! - wish it stayed at 2
```

Ideally I would want the const myArrayLength to not change dynamically as the state of myArray changes so that I can track when `myArrayLength !== myArray.length`

I could create a whole new state: `const [myArrayLength, setMyArrayLength] = useState(myArray.length);` and it would work

But it doesn't feel right because I would never use the setter `setMyArrayLength`

Open to any ideas! Maybe I'm going about this whole thing the wrong way

EDIT :

Thank you all for your answers!

I think simply using them other hooks, useRef or useEffect to the rescue here makes the most sense.I was wondering if there was a way to avoid it but doesn't look like it.

I might go with useRef because it's a one liner, but useEffect to update the length in a new state also makes a lot of sense.

Only thing is it works using `const myArrayLength=useRef(myArray.length)`, I just need to use `myArrayLength.current` to get the value back

Comment: `myArrayLength` is calculated each render (and setting state is async so it's not clear from the snippet where that logging occurs).

Comment: If it is a constant keep it outside. If it is component based keep it in a ref

Comment: when you want  to check when `myArray` is changing use `useEffect`

Comment: I think there's a more fundamental issue here -- _why_ shouldn't `myArrayLength` track the array's length?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do that makes this necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use `useRef` to hold the length of your array. Compare and update its value when needed without causing any rerender.

> When to use useRef() instead of useState()
>
> A rule of thumb is to use useState when you need to re-render the
> component when the state changes and useRef when you don't need to
> re-render the component when the state changes. Here are some examples
> of when to use useRef instead of useState:
>
> - When you need to store a value that does not trigger a re-render when
>   it is updated.
> - When you need to store a value that is not used in the
>   render method.
> - When you need to store a value that persists for the
>   lifetime of the component.

Check out this [link](https://dev.to/trinityyi/when-to-use-useref-instead-of-usestate-3h4o).

Comment: Perfect that works. I need to add `.current` to the ref to get the value. `const myArrayLength=useRef(myArray.length)` ..... `myArrayLength.current` gives me what I need

Comment: Yes, exactly. Awesome!

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to run a function anytime myArray changes, you could use `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => { /* your code here */ }, [myArray])
```

Notice the dependency array `[myArray]`.  That tells React to run the effect if myArray is unequal to myArray from the previous render.

Comment: Yep that woudl've helped as well --- I'm going to go with useRef, since it's shorter code

Answer (score -1):

You could just set your state to empty, set your array, get the length, then set state to array.

```
const [myArray, setMyArray] = useState([]);

const tempArr = ["Some Value", "Some other value"]
const myArrayLength = tempArr.length; 
setMyArray(tempArr);

...
...

setMyArray([ ...myArray, "add a value"]);
```